# zeppelin pyspark how to connect remote spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

My zeppelin is using local spark now.

Got `ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once` when I tried to create a remote SparkContext .

Follow
[multiple SparkContexts error in tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280629/multiple-sparkcontexts-error-in-tutorial)

write below code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

sc.stop()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('train_etl').setMaster('spark://xxxx:7077')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Got another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-6681108227268089746.py", line 363, in <module>
    sc.setJobGroup(jobGroup, jobDesc)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 944, in setJobGroup
    self._jsc.setJobGroup(groupId, description, interruptOnCancel)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setJobGroup'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Enter http://zeppelin_host:zeppelin_port/#/interpreter
2. config parameter `master` of `spark` interpreter (which use for pyspark)  to `spark://xxxx:7077`

Answer (score 0):

by default, Spark automatically creates the SparkContext object named sc, when the PySpark application started.you have to use below line in your code which

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

Get the singleton SQLContext if it exists or create a new one using the given SparkContext.
This function can be used to create a singleton SQLContext object that can be shared across the JVM.

If there is an active SQLContext for current thread, it will be returned instead of the global one.